# Transcrypt and SVG creation

Tags: python, svg, transcrypt

Hi I have managed to create a SVG with Python via Transcrypt. The code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class SVG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.svg   = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
        self.svgNS = self.svg.namespaceURI
        self.circle = document.createElementNS(self.svgNS,'circle')
        self.svg.setAttribute('height', 300)
        self.svg.setAttribute('width', 300)
        self.circle.setAttribute('cx', 150)
        self.circle.setAttribute('cy', 150)
        self.circle.setAttribute('r', 100)
        self.circle.setAttribute('stroke', 'black')
        self.circle.setAttribute('stroke-width', 5)
        self.circle.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
        self.svg.appendChild(self.circle)
        document.body.appendChild(self.svg)

        self.b=document.createElement('br')
        document.body.appendChild(self.b)

        self.h=document.createElement('a')
        self.t=document.createTextNode('A Circle')
        self.h.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', 'http://www.google.com')
        self.h.appendChild(self.t)

        document.body.appendChild(self.h)

graphic = SVG()
```

This works fine when compiling with transcrypt. But if I change the code to this:

```
# svg_10.py
class SVG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.svg   = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
        self.svgNS = self.svg.namespaceURI
        r1_vars = {'x': 10, 'y': 10, 'width': 100, 'height': 20, 'fill':'#ff00ff'}
        self.r1 = self.draw_graphic('rect', r1_vars)
        self.svg.appendChild(self.r1)
        r2_vars = {'x': 20, 'y': 40, 'width': 100, 'height': 40, 'rx': 8, 'ry': 8, 'fill': 'pink', 'stroke':'purple', 'strokeWidth':7 }
        self.r2 = self.draw_graphic('rect', r2_vars)
        self.svg.appendChild(self.r2)
        document.body.appendChild(self.svg)
    
    def draw_graphic(self, kind, vars):
        graphic = document.createElementNS(self.svgNS, kind)
        for key in vars.keys():
            graphic.setAttribute(key, vars[key])
        return graphic

graphic = SVG()
```

I do not get any output though transcrypt runs through without complaining. What went wrong? The html code for displaying it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
        <title>SVG</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
    <script language="javascript" src="__javascript__/svg_10.js"></script>
</html>
```

Still using Transcrypt 3.6 so the header is different. If you use a newer version change it to:

```
<script type="module">import * as svg_10 from './__target__/svg_10.js';window.svg_10 = svg_10;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just found out that the following code seems to work though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class SVG:
    def __init__(self):
        self.svg   = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
        self.svgNS = self.svg.namespaceURI
        self.r1 = self.draw_graphic('rect', 'x:10; y:10; width:100; height:20; fill:#ff00ff')
        self.svg.appendChild(self.r1)
        self.r2 = self.draw_graphic('rect', 'x:20; y:40; width:100; height:40; rx:15; ry:15; fill:pink; stroke:purple; strokeWidth:7')
        self.svg.appendChild(self.r2)
        document.body.appendChild(self.svg)
    
    def draw_graphic(self, kind, variablen):
        graphic = document.createElementNS(self.svgNS, kind)
        variablen = variablen.replace(" ", "")
        elems = variablen.split(";")
        lelem = len(elems)
        for i in range(lelem):
            elem = elems[i]
            # console.log(elem)
            if ":" in elem:
                key, value = elem.split(":")
                graphic.setAttribute(key, value)
        return graphic

graphic = SVG()
```